# Autostart mobile hotspot when starting smartphone

Tags: wifi-hotspot

Is there some way to autostart the mobile hotspot once turning on the smartphone?

We have an external device relying on a mobile hotspot. We need some way to always run mobile hotspot when the phone is alive.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some way to autostart the mobile hotspot once turning on the smartphone?

Yes, you can do this. Note that as a prerequisite your android device needs to be rooted. Head to Play Store and install [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) (a paid app). Open Tasker, provide permanent Root privileges from your installed Root App. After that:

1. Cancel any help section or window for the time being and head to `Profiles` out of the three options :- `Profiles`, `Tasks`, `Scenes`.
2. At the bottom, touch <kbd>+</kbd> `-> Event -> System -> Device Boot`. Touch **Backward key** one time and it will ask to *`Enter task`*.
3. Create a task by choosing `New task` <kbd>+</kbd>. Enter a name for it, touch `right symbol` and you'll be presented with blank screen and some symbols at the bottom.
4. Touch <kbd>+</kbd> `-> Net -> Wifi Tether`. Below option `Set` choose `On`. Touch backward key two times to come back to main screen of app.
5. Touch **Context Menu key** one time and select `Enable Tasker`. If it is already enabled then you'll be having an icon(like lightning) in Android's Status Bar.
6. Make sure that no external app(if any installed) is inhibiting the Tasker app from starting after startup.
7. Reboot or Power-Off and Power-On and you'll see that hotspot gets activated automatically after every reboot.

**NOTE**:- Depending upon the apps in Startup your system may take some more seconds to start hotspot but eventually it will do by itself.